# how to convert Virtualbox vdi into Virtual machine?

Tags: virtual-machines, virtualbox

how can I convert Virtual box **vdi** into Virtual machine? Preferably under OSX.

It seems to me that VMware-converter-all-4.3.0 cannot do it for me.

NOTE: I tried to run VMware converter under running Virtualbox but `FAILED: Unable to create a VSS snapshot of the source volume(s). Error code:
2147754758 (0x80042306).` Maybe that happened because I have x: disk mapped from my OSX?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this by installing vmware converter inside the virtual machine, then running it and selecting convert this "physical" / "local" computer... Just set the destination for the new VM to a shared folder on the network or on the host computer.

Should work, I haven't done it on OSX, but the logic is there.

Hope that helps

Comment: @lysdexic: I tried that but `FAILED: Unable to create a VSS snapshot of the source volume(s). Error code: 2147754758 (0x80042306).`

Comment: maybe because I have disk x: as a shared one from my OSX?

Comment: Yes, I've seen that before, if X: is a mapped drive then it won't be able to make a copy of that disk. You will need to unmap it or unselect it during the conversion process. Is this the destination for the new VM, that would not work either.

Comment: Also, if that still doesn't work... it looks like there is an export option from virtual box. It will export as an OVF (open virtual format, I think), then you should be able to convert the OVF to a vmdk using vmware converter. -I've never used that method, but looks like it could work, it would take a little research.

Comment: I take back the comment about X: not being able to be used as destination. That should work as long as you uncheck X: during the conversion process. Best of luck!

Comment: @lysdexic: disk X is not included for the conversion so I do not know what to do about the error. VMWare Converter won't recognise OVF file :-(

Comment: Ah, check this out, there is a little bit to it... 

http://blogs.techrepublic.com.com/window-on-windows/?p=2997

Comment: Also, even if X: is not checked, you may need to go ahead and disconnect the mapped drive if you try to convert it using the "convert local machine" method again.

Comment: but I use the X: drive to save the new converted machine onto. Old machine doens't have enough space so that's why I am doing this exercise.

Answer (score 1):

There's a tool you can use called [SmartVDK](http://www.smartdeploy.com/Products/Downloads.aspx) (It's the download at the bottom of that page) that allows you to convert .vhd, .vmdk, .vdi, and .hdd to any of these formats. It's free for non-commercial use.

Hope that helps.